# Android TTS has more languages available than found in settings

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am using Android's TTS (using Google's engine) and I am quite confused with the settings and language support. This is how I detect if a language is available:

```
if (tts.isLanguageAvailable(currentLocale) >= TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE) {
    ttsAvailable = true;
    tts.setLanguage(currentLocale);
    tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new VPUtteranceProgressListener());
}
```

which works fine. In fact, it works better than expected. The default Google engine does not say it has a Dutch voice (as found in Settings > Input > Text-to-Speech), yet the engine claims it is available and also actually speaks Dutch. Did Google silently add TTS voices and not open them to the settings?

Comment: Look at this page. See if it answers your question: http://www.apps4android.org/?p=3695

Comment: @BobMalooga thanks, but it doesn't say anything about TTS voices.

Comment: If a locale is supported, then it would be logical to expect the TTS voice also to be supported accordingly.

Comment: @BobMalooga, it wasn't a few months ago. I had to install an external Dutch voice. Also, speech recognition is also not supported for all supported UI languages.

Comment: Uh... strange. Maybe there's some difference in **WHICH** TTS Engine you are using: Pico or Google (not even to mention 3rd party ones).

Comment: @BobMalooga I had the SVOX installed, I just removed it now. The Google engine claims it supports Dutch and also actually support it. (As expected by the way, as Dutch recognition is available by default.)

Comment: Here is maybe the mystery solution? http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/03/05/google-releases-huge-text-to-speech-tts-for-android-update-v3-0-with-high-quality-voices-new-languages-and-ui-changes-apk-download/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50603/discussion-between-bart-friederichs-and-bob-malooga)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have 50 reputation to comment so I'll answer it here.

A simple explanation might be that when an Android firmware is released, it tends to target a particular region, say Europe. So, the European firmware might have pretty much all the Western, plus some, or all Eastern European languages built into the firmware.

However, TTS is a "service" within the firmware, wrapped neatly in an app, with some supporting Java / Android classes. And since it is a "service", it can be bundled with all, or as many languages as possible that are currently being supported via TTS.

So, you'll always get this difference in languages support between the firmware and the "services" contain in the firmware.

I hope the above explanation makes sense.

UPDATE 1:

With regard to *"Dutch is not in this list, yet the engine does support it and speaks Dutch"*, this could be an oversight, or lack of due diligence in software quality assurance, made by Google or the Android device manufacturer, or both. So, even though Dutch is not listed, you can still call the locale and use it in TTS. Perhaps, you need to log this issue with Google. Maybe they can shed further light into this matter.

Comment: It makes sense, but doesn't solve my question. The Google TTS app gives a list of supported languages. Dutch is not in this list, yet the engine *does* support it and speaks Dutch.